# How to convert a string to a date, without losing the formatting

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have this date `2015-11-06T18:00:00-0500`

My format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

i try

```
let startDateString = "2015-11-06T18:00:00-0500"
let format = NSDateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

let startDateBtnEnd = format.dateFromString(startDateString)
println("startDateBtnEnd 2 \(startDateBtnEnd)")
```

But the log is 
`startDateBtnEnd 2 Optional(2015-11-07 00:00:00 +0000)`

Comment: That makes no sense. NSDate represents an absolute point in time.  It does not have a format (and no time zone).

Comment: Dates and strings are different. You can't log a date without converting it to a string in some way. `NSDate` doesn't use an ISO format when generating its description.

Comment: `2015-11-06T18:00:00-0500` represents the same time as `2015-11-07 00:00:00 +0000`. The time zone is a function of how the date is represented as a string. Don't worry that the `println` displayed it as it did. If you care about what time zone the resulting string shows, use another date formatter to create that string in the desired time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDate` stores dates in UTC. You can convert it to the same moment in time in any timezone. But after losing too many neurons to mentally convert `NSDate` from one timezone to another, I decided to add my own extension to `NSDate` to print it out in the local timezone instead:

```
extension NSDate {
    func toString(timeZone: NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()) -> String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        formatter.timeZone = timeZone

        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}

// Usage:
print("startDateBtnEnd 2 \(startDateBtnEnd.toString())")
```